# 1 centered button, how can I put another button 10dp above the centered button? Android, IntelliJ

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I have a view with two buttons. One (button2) Ive put android:layout_centerInParent="true" and it is in centered in the screen where it should be. Now I want the other (button1) to be placed above button 2 with a margin of 10dp. I am using a relative layout. How can I write this in xml? Should I use some other layout to make it work?

My .xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bakgrundsbild"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nybutton"
            android:text="@string/las_sollefteabladet"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nybutton"
        android:text="@string/annonsorer"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Use your layout like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="annonsorer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:text="las_sollefteabladet" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Add images to that..

Comment: It is not working..button1 dissapears from the screen with this code.

Comment: It worked when I took your code without images but when I put in images for buttons and background button1 jumps away.. Weird

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_above="@+id/button2"

use this in Button1(centered position) code